# Does the spin of an atom affect the velocity of it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, velocity

Does the spin of an atom affect the velocity of it?

If so, in layman terms, can someone explain to me why/how the spin of an atom can effect velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please allow me a little leeway here. An atom is made up of different parts: electrons, neutrons and protons, as you know, so let me describe one of those parts first and then come back to the atom in a later question, as it is too complicated to describe the spin of an atom unless you follow the way the parts of the atom works first.

I would take the electron first.

In layman terms, this is the basic idea. The spin of an electron does not affect it's speed  in any way, but it can affect its direction of travel, if we put it in a magnetic field,  because an electron itself  is a tiny magnet.

I will stick to the intrinsic spin of an electron, the spin around its own axis, rather than the revolution of the electron around the atom, as I think it is the former point you are interested in.

Now comes the hard part, (as you have to give up every bit of common sense you might have, I am sorry about that).

You are asking about the quantum world, which has a different set of rules  from the classical world that we live in, so do not expect any of your assumptions to be applicable. Trying to apply common sense and classical rules to the quantum world, is like trying to play American football using baseball rules, it won't make sense most of the time.

One example of this is to ask you to forget everything I said about revolution and the axis in the paragraph above.

An electron does not spin as a soccer ball, it might be dimensionless, (that is a point particle), it does not have an axis and it takes two "revolutions" to get back to its orginal position, not like a soccer ball which takes 1 360 degree  revolution.

Because of that, the word **spin** will always make you think of a tiny ball, so I will call it **spinlike** from now on.

So why do we use the word spin? Because in the 1920s, we discovered that the electron had a bit more energy that we could explain, so we **totally imagined** that it was a tiny ball, and the extra energy came from its spinning around this axis.

An electron  only has two directions of spinlike.  In the 3 D world that we live in, this makes no sense, but the electron is a quantum particle,  it does not play by classical rules.

We say it has spinlike up, or it has spinlike down, again forget the ball idea, the words up and down are just used to distinguish the state it is in, either spinlike up or spinlike down. The amount of spinlike an electon has always stays the same, we can change its spinlike direction by magnetic fields,  but we cannot make it spinlike any faster or slower than the amount of spinlike it has.

We don't know exactly what an electron "is", we only know it's properties,  what it can do and what it can't do.

We don't even know where the electron will be at a given time, we can only say it will probably be in a certain position, so ideas like velocity are not really applicable, but they are so handy that we use them.

Answer (score 1):

In case of an isolated atom - or molecule for that matter - the answer is no, since there is no force acting on the spin. However, if you introduce an external force, for instance inhomogeneous electric or magnetic fields, one can change the velocity of an atom or molecule flying through such a field. The best known example is the Stern-Gerlach experiment in which silver atoms were deflected (the orthogonal velocity component changes) by inhomogeneous magnetic fields.

In general, the force acting on a particle is given by
$$ F=-\frac{dW}{dr}$$
where $W$ is the internal energy of the particle (in some field) and $r$ is the coordinate vector.
If you have a particle that has an internal energy that depends on (the orientation of) its spin, such as the Zeeman effect we can rewrite the above equation as follows (in case of a magnetic field $B$)
$$ F =-\frac{dW}{dB}\frac{dB}{dr}$$
Implying that the field has to be inhomogeneous ($dB/dr\neq0$) to change the velocity of the particle.